# Handling Long Running Duplicate HTTP Requests

Tags: php, mysql, apache, httpwebrequest

What would be a good way to deal with receiving duplicate HTTP requests on the server?

I have reports on a LAMP web app which take ~ 30 seconds to build on the server and return to the client. Clients get impatient and run the report again before the first finishes. This bogs down the server. Is there any way to handle/prevent this server side?

Comment: Could you pre-generate the reports over-night, and then just link to that instead? That won't work if the clients are getting their own customized reports, but if it's the same one each time, it should work nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the fact that a job is already running somewhere.

In your code that generates the report, check if one is already running. If so, don't run another.

When the report is done generating or some timeout expires to handle exceptional conditions, un-store that fact.

You can use a database, a memcached server, redis, a text file, write to shared memory...

Answer (score 1):

You can try returning a 202 response until whatever you are building on the server is done, then serve a cached copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, telling the user that something is being processed tends to be done with AJAX.

Typically, you'd send the request to your server, which would then return a 202 response and an address (possibly with a UUID) for the browser to find the result (which you wouldn't necessarily display directly, but keep in the background of your script: you can also display this directly for clients that don't support JavaScript).

Then, you would make subsequent requests in the background to that address, and display the result when it's ready.

This approach not only has the advantage of being more user friendly, but it's also more robust against disconnections.

Answer (score 0):

30 seconds is just way too long to let a user wait in todays web app world. Google searches the whole web in 1/100th of that time. What makes your web app more advanced or data consuming. If your one instance can't handle it even after optimization you better scale it out to the cloud (or more servers). If it's really so demanding, divide it into subtasks that can run in parallell from several instances.

For your direct question, rather than an answer to the question you did not ask; the answers above holds some tricks. Either you can generate the frequently requested queries before they even come - or you can make only the first request to the rendering and wait for that request to finish before you send the result.

Comment: However powerful computers have become, there are still a number of tasks that may take more than 30 seconds to complete, in particular because not everything is entirely parallelisable. "*scale it out to the cloud*" sounds like you've been reading too much marketing material...

Comment: Or that you can just reach much higher peak processing capacity with less investments by utilizing cloud services ...

Comment: And the point is that you can not let users wait for that long if you want to keep your visitors. If some task needs that long processing time, it needs to be transformed into a background service and also be seen as a background job by the visitor on the site. Everything else will drive visitors away and of course most requests will then be cancelled.

Comment: Again, not every task can be split into sub-tasks in such a way that what remains serial can be done under 30 seconds, even on a powerful modern machine. Throwing it onto "the cloud" will not help in these cases (which do still exist). The question doesn't specify what kind of report is being run nor what kind of users are expected: speculating on whether the visitor will go away is pointless.

Comment: Waiting on a webpage request for 30 seconds WILL make users cancel it - no matter if they get several warnings before they press a button or if they are drilled staff inhouse. Throwing it from a  limited enviroment to one with more processing power WILL help almost every possible case.

Comment: I think we all agree that the users need to be informed if they have to wait for that sort of period of time. My point was only about the assumption you make that throwing a problem onto the cloud will make those reports appear in under 30 seconds: (a) not all problems are parallelisable in this way and (b) achieving that parallelisation will have a cost that may or may not make it worth doing (the cost analysis exercise depends entirely on the problem and environment, of course).